# Detecting WiFi Tethering traffic using TrafficStats API?

Tags: android, network-traffic, tethering

Anyone know how this can be done? The TrafficStats source code notes that there is a supposed to be a special UID (UID_TETHERING) used to track this, but using the getUidTxBytes and getUidRxBytes APIs always return zero.

I've seen other apps have this feature and I was wondering if the TrafficStats API is the way to go about tracking tethering traffic.